# How to regularly check for RSS/email-like updates online with iOS4

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, background, multitasking

Is it possible to have an App (running iOS4 on hardware supporting multi-tasking) which starts on iPhone startup and then regularly checks for online updates (every 15 minutes) and then refresh the badge, so the user can see how many unread items there are with-out having a push-server?

I was hoping this would be possible with iOS4 Programming Guide seems to suggest it is only possible to to this regarding Locations tracking, VoIP and playing background audio. There is also the possibility to do local-push notifications, but I don't see to find how to trigger a specific function that way.

Thanks in advance for any help!

edit:
Just having read a bit more, if the application is in the background/inactive state, and I son want to update the badge-number without displaying a message, is there an action triggered like didReceiveLocalNotification? There must be a way to schedule something on a regular basis (like email checking) without having to implement a full server-push-nitification system!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to have an App ... which starts on iPhone startup and then regularly checks for online updates (every 15 minutes) and then refresh the badge

As you already figured out, the answer is no.

Comment: Well, it looks like it. It would just be so much easier (and thinking of iTouch more so than iPhone) so much better for battery life not to have push-notifications.
The use of UIBackgroundModes:voip would not be any chance be able to be tweaked?
Neither a beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler which fires a new one when it is finished?